# Static IP and netplan stop working a couple days after fresh install Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, systemd-networkd, netplan

Having some major issues with networking on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Fresh install. I set a static IP during install which worked for a couple days and remained set after multiple reboots. Now the interface shows no IP. It seems when I set that IP it did generate a netplan that appears correct however netplan apply does nothing.

This happened to me previously as well on the previous install. I had been messing with some DNS stuff so I figured I'd just reimage the machine and not touch any of the network utilities this time and I still am having the issue.

The issue occurs about a day and a half after install seemingly randomly. Was not using the machine when the issue began and the only thing I have done so far on this install is set up a couple docker containers with samba and SFTP.

Contents of my 50-cloud-init.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s25:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.0.32/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Terminal output from netplan --debug apply

```
** (generate:2227): DEBUG: 23:11:19.520: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:2227): DEBUG: 23:11:19.520: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2227): DEBUG: 23:11:19.520: enp0s25: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2227): DEBUG: 23:11:19.520: Generating output files..
** (generate:2227): DEBUG: 23:11:19.520: NetworkManager: definition enp0s25 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp0s25 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.32/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: docker0
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: br-98e8ea9c70cb
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp0s25
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-98e8ea9c70cb
```

My ifconfig

```
br-98e8ea9c70cb: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:51:a6:a3:66  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:d5:d6:46:8e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:24:7e:00:e0:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xfc500000-fc520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7926  bytes 592108 (592.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7926  bytes 592108 (592.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the static IP in a correct manner? See [This tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). Remeber, configuring static IP in 18.04 is different from 16.04.

Other than that i would recommend to see if any other host in the network has "stole" the IP, maybe try with an other static IP for the host. Make sure to `ping` the new static IP in order to make sure it is available.

Finally make sure you run `sudo netplan apply`, or `sudo netplan --debug apply` in order to run the new configurations.

My best guess is that `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` is configured wrong so go through it carefully one more time.

Good luck.

Comment: I will take a look that that tutorial when I have a minute and give it a go. The odd thing is that I didn't make the netplan config. Ubuntu did when I entered the static IP in the live install gui.

Comment: Hmm, i bet somthing is wrong in your configuration as mentioned. I have followed that exact tuturials on several ubuntu 18.04 VMs, has worked for me all those times.

Comment: I have updated my post with netplan configs and debug outputs

Comment: what are the output of  `ifconfig` ?

Comment: I have added it to the original post now